# Wrong count of table rows using jquery $('table > tbody > tr ').length

Tags: jquery

[Inspect table 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6rBm.png)
[Inspect table 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZvU2.png)
Table inside modal, I load table using ajax upon showing of modal.
Another problem I encounter using $('table').find('tbody > tr').length gives exact row count but when I remove rows using .remove() then count rows the row count did not update.

```
//Execution for counting rows
$('#BtnSaveChanges').click(function() {
    console.log('test');
    console.log($('#tabUpdate > tbody > tr').length);
})

// Remove current row ( Trash icon)
$(document).on('click','a.removerow',function(){
 $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

Comment: impossible to help with the data provided.

Comment: Hi @epascarello, what data u need to check sir?

Comment: i provided screenshots

Comment: I suggest that you reproduce
 in jsfiddle

Comment: _gives exact column count_ do you mean exact row count? Please update the question to clatify. I also resuggest reproducing in jsfiddle

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Row count sir sorry,.

Answer (score -1):

I got it, by using this:

```
$(document).find('#modal-xl .modal-body').find('table > tbody > tr').length
```

I'm thinking that using `$('#tabUpdate > tbody > tr').length` includes other table rows..